# How to find people from the UK or Ireland interested for home exchange or hospitality exchange?

Tags: uk, online-resources, ireland, cyprus, homestay

I live in Cyprus and have extra bedrooms for renting out, which I do occasionally but not often enough to make serious income. The income for poor people here is 480 euro/month, which is not as high as in UK but the climate conditions and other elements are far better (sun, sea, weather, etc). I assume maybe some people want to voluntarily cancel their 'on the dole' benefits in UK, and make a new start abroad but are impeded by high cost of relocation. I seek for a way to relocate to UK and allow a UK person to cheaply relocated to EU part of Cyprus. This means that they (and me) must voluntarily say goodbye to benefits because we essentially immigrate.

---

> Edit by [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow): "on the dole" = informal English meaning registered as
>   unemployed and receiving benefit from the government.  Or otherwise
>   receiving welfare.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39225/discussion-on-question-by-anna-zenonos-how-to-find-people-from-the-uk-or-ireland).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest my site, [ExchangeMouse](https://exchangemouse.com) where you can search among all 60+ home exchange websites, and find matches for a Cyprus-UK home swap. There is an option for long term exchanges, a "few months" is regarded such.